# Encountering Unhandled error in Sanity on localhost

Tags: node.js, blockchain, sanity, daap

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'jsonType')
    at validateNonObjectFieldsProp (/static/js/app.bundle.js:169457:16)
    at _default (/static/js/app.bundle.js:169425:155)
    at visitors.reduce._objectSpread._problems (/static/js/app.bundle.js:167933:17)
    at Array.reduce ()
    at /static/js/app.bundle.js:167932:21
    at /static/js/app.bundle.js:167951:70
    at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168067:12
    at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168082:95
    at Array.forEach ()
    at traverseSchema (/static/js/app.bundle.js:168081:9)
```

Showing the given error while performing the sanity start command, but  it not showing on command line. While visiting the localhost website there's the error is showing this. I have tried downgrading the versions for sanity but still not solved this issue.

Comment: Can you please post `dependencies` and `devDependencies` from package.json?

Answer (score 1):

[You missed type document in schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXlvX.png)

```js
Eg:
export default {
  name: "user",
  title: "User",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "userName",
      title: "UserName",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "image",
      title: "Image",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
};
```